# Pull data from xml file to list view in c#

Tags: c#, xml

How to pull data from xml file to a list view in c#, get the data inside the tags of the xml document ..

**I have a xml file like this ..**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Nmap/nmap.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<!-- Nmap 6.25 scan initiated Fri Feb 15 13:34:46 2013 as: nmap -T4 -A -v -oX - 10.100.95.0 10.100.95.255 -->
<nmaprun scanner="nmap" args="nmap -T4 -A -v -oX - 10.100.95.0 10.100.95.255" start="1360915486" startstr="Fri Feb 15 13:34:46 2013" version="6.25" xmloutputversion="1.04">
<scaninfo type="syn" protocol="tcp" numservices="1000" services=""/>
<verbose level="1"/>
<debugging level="0"/>
<taskbegin task="ARP Ping Scan" time="1360915488"/>
<taskend task="ARP Ping Scan" time="1360915489" extrainfo="2 total hosts"/>
<host><status state="down" reason="no-response" reason_ttl="0"/>
<address addr="10.100.95.0" addrtype="ipv4"/>
</host>
<host><status state="down" reason="no-response" reason_ttl="0"/>
<address addr="10.100.95.255" addrtype="ipv4"/>
</host>
<runstats><finished time="1360915489" timestr="Fri Feb 15 13:34:49 2013" elapsed="3.16" summary="Nmap done at Fri Feb 15 13:34:49 2013; 2 IP addresses (0 hosts up) scanned in 3.16 seconds" exit="success"/><hosts up="0" down="2" total="2"/>
</runstats>
</nmaprun>
```

And I want to extract all the list of **addr** address and **addrtype** inside the address tag in the list view grid and display it accordingly in each row of the list view ..

list should be like this ..
Addr               Addrtype
192.168.1.45        ipv4
192.164.4.56        ipv4

etc..

please help me thanks in advance ..

Comment: What have your tried? That means: Show the code you have so far.

Comment: Show some of your effort

Comment: `String xpath = path + "/NGS_Net_Scanner/IP_Range_Scan13.34.43_.xml";

            var xdoc = XDocument.Load(xpath);
            var addrs = x.Descendants().Elements("address")
                   .Select(y =>
                   {
                       ListViewItem item1 = new ListViewItem(y.Attribute("addr").Value);
                       item1.SubItems.Add(y.Attribute("addrtype").Value);
                       return item1;
                   });

            ListViewItem.Items.AddRange(addrs);`

[main]I have error stating tha listView - doesnot exists in the current context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(@"c:\temp\arg\s.xml");
var addrs = xdoc.Descendants().Elements("address")
               .Select(y => new {
                                 Name = y.Attribute("addr").Value, 
                                 Value =   y.Attribute("addrtype").Value
                                });
```

This will get you all the address as you want

```
foreach(var addr in addrs)
{
    ListViewItem item1 = new ListViewItem(addr.Name);
    item1.SubItems.Add(addr.Value);
    //We have a ListView named listview
    listview.Items.Add(item1);
}
```

or we can do it simpler like this

```
var addrs = xdoc.Descendants().Elements("address")
                   .Select(y => {
                                    ListViewItem item1 = new ListViewItem(y.Attribute("addr").Value);
                                    item1.SubItems.Add(y.Attribute("addrtype").Value);
                                    return item1;
                                });

listView.Items.AddRange(addrs);
```

Comment: Hey it is throwing two exceptions
First- x is doesnot exist in the current context ..
Second - listView doesn't exist in the current context ..

Comment: lol. just changed x for xdoc and listview doesn't exist that's true, that must be your listview, it's a snippet not a real working code.... lol

Comment: still I am stuck where listView is throwing an error stating that -"listView doesn't exist in the current context .."

**please Help me out ..**

Comment: of course it doesn't exist you have to created and named and change that variable name at your will.....I can't do anything further

Comment: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.

this error occured when I tried to find the path of the xml file ..

Answer (score 1):

answer 1.- Use linq to XML and collect data in list or collection after that u can bind data with your list view control.

answer 2.- Use data set

```
    Dim xmlDatapath As String = "yourxml file path\111.xml"

    Dim xmlData As String = File.ReadAllText(xmlDatapath)
    Dim stream As StringReader = New StringReader(xmlData)
    Dim reader As XmlTextReader = New XmlTextReader(stream)
    Dim xmlDS As New DataSet()
    xmlDS.ReadXml(reader)
```

and bind your data with list view control.
I hope this will help you.